# Trying to add external JS and CSS files to my rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vendor

I am trying to add external css and JS to my rails app. I added the relevant files in vendor/assets/javascripts and vendor/assets/stylesheets.

I tried to load these files in my app by adding these lines to application.scss :

```
@import "stylesheets/nice-select.css";
@import "stylesheets/style.css";
```

and these lines to application.js :

```
//= require javascripts/fastclick.js
//= require javascripts/nice_select.js
//= require javascripts/prism.js
```

When I try to launch my app after restarting the server I get :

couldn't find file 'javascripts/fastclick.js' with type 'application/javascript'

However the file fastclick.js is here inside vendor/assets/javascripts.

What am I doing wrong when I try to include these external files ?

Comment: You need to specify the `vendor` directory in your `reuqire` and `@import` statements. E.g. `//= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/fastclick.js` and `@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/nice-select.css"`. Give these a try.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Rails 4? If so, you shouldn't need to include `javascripts` in your script path:

```
//= require fastclick.js
//= require nice_select.js
//= require prism.js
```

Should work for `vendor/assets/javascripts/fastclick.js`, etc...

If it still doesn't work, add the following in your configuration block within `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'javascripts')
```